# How to optimise website to display nicely on mobile

Tags: html, css

This my screenshot on the desktop browser

[image]

Everything look big on desktop browser. But when I view on mobile browser the layout becomes very small. So did I miss something in the html/css code, because this website basically I used just plain html/css nothing fancy.

Could anyone point me out ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you set the following viewport meta tag inside your `<head>`, otherwise the text will be too small:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 1):

Resize elements when the browser window goes under a certain size with [`@media` queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries).

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  div {
    width: 400px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually mobile-view optimization for a website is a detailed and extensive topic but for your case, my recommendation is to increase your fonts a little.